# Indexing on a timestamp firebase

Tags: android, indexing, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to do an `orderByChild` operation in my Android application, and I'm getting the warning saying this: `Using an unspecified index. Consider adding '".indexOn": "timestamp"' at users/4Gc9OgFWw5hwr2YFxbfwLgyAp1V2/posts to your security and Firebase Database rules`

This is how I structured my database:

[image: Database]

This is the rule I tried to add to my database:

```
{
"rules": {
".read": "auth != null",
".write": "auth != null",
  "users": {
    "uid": {
      "posts": {
            ".indexOn": "timestamp"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

However, it is still giving me this warning. How can I fix it? I saw somewhere that you can just use any variable for the uid children and that's why I have the `uid` variable in there, but I have also tried it without.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be `$uid` not `uid` in your rules

checkout [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#variables)

```
{
    "rules":{
        ".read":"auth != null",
        ".write":"auth != null",
        "users":{
            "$uid":{
                "posts":{
                    ".indexOn":"timestamp"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of indexing `orderByValue:` and `orderByChild`

**Indexing with orderByValue::**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "scores": {
      ".indexOn": ".value"
    }
  }
}
```

**Indexing with orderByChild:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "employee": {
      ".indexOn": ["empName", "empId", "designation"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Multilevel Indexing:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "employee": {
      ".indexOn": ["empName","empId","branchDetails/branch",
        "branchDetails/branchLocation","branchDetails/branchId"]
    }
  }
}
```

You can also refer to this link for the Firebase Real-Time Database Data Indexing.

[Firebase Real-Time Database Data Indexing](https://medium.com/@kodagvikram/firebase-real-time-database-indexing-83f16e7adf9a?source=friends_link&sk=dbc8a619b98b4a331a0f6caae9bdbdc2)